# Error importing developer account in Xcode 7.1.1

Tags: xcode, certificate, profile

I have Xcode 7.1.1 installed on a new MBP and on my mid 2010 iMac. The MBP is my dev machine, has my developer account configured (Im an admin) and I'm able to build, sign, and test on my devices. I want to transfer my developer account to my iMac.

I export my account on my MBP which creates a file with a .developerprofile extension. In Xcode accounts on my iMac I select Import developer account. I choose the file and enter the password and receive the error:

"An unknown error occurred trying to open the file filename.developerprofile" Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. My issue was that I was transfering the .developerprofile file to the public folder on my imac and was attempting to import it from there. The public folder has restrictions and I was prompted for my admin password in order to move the file out of the public folder. Once I relocated the file outside of the public folder I was able to successfully import the developer account!